# Pythonic way to check if a set in list is present in a different set

Tags: python, set

I have a list of sets

```
lst = [s1, s2, s3]
```

where

```
s1 = set([1, 2, 3])
s2 = set([2, 3, 4])
s3 = set([2, 4, 6])
```

and I have another set

```
set1 = set([1, 2, 3, 5])
```

So when I do `lst - set1` I should get `set()`. One way of doing this is just going through each element of `lst` and then do minus with `set1`. I want to know if there is any pythonic way of doing this.

For Example:

```
s1 = set([1, 2, 3, 4])
s2 = set([2, 3, 4])
s3 = set([2, 4, 6])

lst = [s1,s2,s3]

set1 = set([1, 2, 3, 5, 4])
```

So I need to check if any of the element in the list `lst` is present in `set1`

Comment: unclear what the expected output is

Comment: `lst - set1` is plain undefined. You can't have a difference between a `list` and `set`. Do you want an *element wise* difference, i.e. `[subset - set1 for subset in lst]`? Or should the entire list be interpreted as a flat set?

Comment: Shouldn't `lst - set1` be `{4,6}`?

Comment: _So when I do lst - set1 I should get set()._ why? If it's element-wise operation, I would expect `[empty_set, set(4), set(2,4,6)]`. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I just want to check if I get the empty_set or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of differences between sets you could use a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

```
my_set = set([1, 2, 3, 5])

set_list = [
    set([1, 2, 3]),
    set([2, 3, 4]),
    set([2, 4, 6]),
]

# find differences between sets in list and my_set, remove empty sets
[set_item - my_set for set_item in set_list if set_item - my_set]
# returns [set([4]), set([4, 6])]

# to return only empty sets
[set_item - my_set for set_item in set_list if not set_item - my_set]
```

The list comprehension loops over your list of sets `for set_item in set_list`. It then ensures that the result set isn't empty `if set_item - my_set`. Finally, it returns the result `set_item - my_set` at the left side of the statement.

Comment: I just want to check if the set present in the list can be covered by the other set. So though I will get the above results but I am more interested in seeing the set() result. One way to do is loop through the element in the list and check individually but I just wanted to know is there any pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: That's exactly what a list comprehension does. It loops through lists and lets you perform simple checks or transformations on the items. What part of my answer isn't giving you the results you want?

Comment: I needed to check for empty sets and your second example is doing that. I want to know is list comprehension faster than the native technique(looping through the elements in the list and then checking the difference one by one)

Comment: There is no difference in performance; Both techniques are doing the same thing under the hood. You asked if there was a more "pythonic" way of doing it and list comprehensions are a python-specific way of dealing with iterating.

Comment: Unless you're actually running into performance bottlenecks, you shouldn't concern yourself with speed. This problem in particular has no performance shortcut. Whether you use the `in` operator or a list comprehension, it always has to loop over the entire list to filter it or find a result.

What matters is how readable your code is and, depending on who you ask, a list comprehension is a more readable pattern when it comes to python code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` operator. It works with any array-like container including lists, tuples, sets and dictionary keys.

```
set_list = [set(1, 2, 3), set(2, 3, 4), set(2, 4, 6)]

# returns True
set([1,2,3]) in set_list

# returns False
set([5, 6, 7]) in set_list

# returns False, just to show that types must match
[1, 2, 3] in set_list
```

Comment: My set1 has more elements so this will give False

Comment: what about s1 = set([1, 2, 3,4])
s2 = set([2, 3, 4])
s3 = set([2, 4, 6])   

lst=[s1,s2,s3]

set1 = set([1, 2, 3,5,4])

set1 in lst.....It gives False where as I would like to have True

Comment: You need to explain what you expect a positive result to be in your question.